# Is it possible to have a custom parameter from application dashboard in kusto query?

Tags: botframework, azure-application-insights

I'm working on an application built on top of Azure services (Chatbot on bot framework).
In Log Analytics I need to write a Kusto query which will be shown as time chart on the application dashboard (Application insights overview dashboard).
Kusto query has a date parameter (timestamp> date) where the date should be provided from the dashboard and not be some constant value (the query is working with a preset date).

Is it possible to provide custom dates from the application dashboard/time chart? I couldn't find any solution for it in the docs.

Comment: It is not clear what dashboard is used, and therefore the answer cannot be provided. Please edit the question with a reference to a service.

Comment: its azure application insights dashboard. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/overview-dashboard.Thats will update the same in question.Also please let me know if you have any solution

Comment: I have added a tag for application-insights and removed tag of dashboards.